# Scaling Spring Batch using AsyncItemProcessor and AsyncItemWriter

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to write a solution to scale a spring batch. In the spring batch it's reading data (600 000) from the MySQL database and then process it and update the status of each processed row as 'Completed'.

I am using `AsyncItemProcessor` and `AsyncItemWriter` for scaling the spring batch.

**Problem:**

If I run the spring batch synchronously then it's taking same or less time while running the spring batch asynchronously. I am not getting the benefit of using multi threading.

```html
package com.example.batchprocessing;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.async.AsyncItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

 @Autowired
 public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

 @Autowired
 public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
 

    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<Person> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setSql("SELECT * from people");
        reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());

        return reader;
    }



 @Bean
 public PersonItemProcessor processor() {

  return new PersonItemProcessor();
 }

 @Bean
 public AsyncItemProcessor<Person, Person> asyncItemProcessor() throws Exception {

  ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
  executor.setCorePoolSize(30);
  executor.setMaxPoolSize(50);
  executor.setQueueCapacity(10000);
  executor.setThreadNamePrefix("BatchProcessing-");
  executor.afterPropertiesSet();

  AsyncItemProcessor<Person, Person> asyncProcessor = new AsyncItemProcessor<>();
  asyncProcessor.setDelegate(processor());
  asyncProcessor.setTaskExecutor(executor);
  asyncProcessor.afterPropertiesSet();

  return asyncProcessor;
 }

 @Bean
 public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
  return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
   .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
   .sql("UPDATE people set status= 'completed' where person_id= :id")
   .dataSource(dataSource)
   .build();
 }

    
 @Bean
 public AsyncItemWriter<Person> asyncItemWriter() {
  AsyncItemWriter<Person> asyncWriter = new AsyncItemWriter<>();
  asyncWriter.setDelegate(writer(null));

  return asyncWriter;
 }

 @Bean
 public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
  return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
   .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
   .listener(listener)
   .flow(step1)
   .end()
   .build();
 }

 @Bean
 public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) throws Exception {

  return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
   .<Person, Person> chunk(10000)
   .reader(reader(null))
   //.processor(processor())
   //.writer(writer)
   .processor((ItemProcessor) asyncItemProcessor())
   .writer(asyncItemWriter())
   //.throttleLimit(30)
   .build();
 }
 
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the `AsyncItemProcessor` taking more/same time as synchronous processing? Usually it should take less time. I can see in the log multiple thread is working but eventually the end time is the same as synchronous processing.

Comment: `AsyncItemProcessor` is useful when processing items is the bottleneck. Adding more threads does not necessarily mean things will go faster. In fact, there is a breakeven point where it could be slower (due to thread management and context switching overhead). I see nothing wrong with your config, but I can't say why it is taking more/same time as a synchronous execution without running the code. That said, have you tried a multi-threaded step before moving to the more elaborate async processor/writer approach?

Comment: I guess you are testing this on localhost where the network latency is pretty small and thus the benefit is not that big.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to @5019386, asyncItemProcessor is helpful when processing an item is expensive. One suggestion that I can make is to move the code to create ThreadPoolTaskExecutor into a separate block as a bean so that you can avoid creating threads.